# Ubuntu 14 LTS crashed to start run

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Don't know what title put in. My problem is: The last night all was running ok so I closed the pc like always. The next morning (yesterday) my mum opened the pc to send an email but, I don't know if she did more than that because when I arrived at home at night the pc wouldn't run.

I have a password session so after write it, I'm getting stuck in the loading page, I tried to watch what was happening pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> I mean, any terminal without interface (I suck on sysop things) and it appears.

What should I do? I tried to put in a ISO runnable in a USB but the pc doesn't detect it... -.-

Thanks a lot!

[image: First photo, just the first request]

[image: I waited a bit to take the photo]

Comment: pictures show a drive problem, did disk make a strange noise ?

Comment: @Archemar beat me to it, looks like a drive failure

Comment: @Archemar well, I did nothing rare so... its why I am freaking out hahaha anyway, the System didn't tell anything about it before and when i try to boot the pc it just makes the typical sound like 'bip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a BIOS-related problem. Go into it, and make sure that the SATA mode for your disk is **AHCI**, not IDE. Reboot, let us know.

Comment: totally! really thanks mate! But why has it changed? its weird.... thanks a lot mate